# Bought used bike, Shimano derailleur does not work - how to repair or replace?

Tags: repair, derailleur

[image: this is my current one, a Shimano deore, dont see the model]
So I'm new to biking and I purchased a really good bike at a reasonable price. It's a 7 speed bike and as you can see the derailleur is messed up. I'm not sure how to find one that will work. I found another Shimano Deore model: RD-M53P SGS. Can anyone tell me if this will work? If not do you know one that will? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't know why this is getting downvoted. OP has a 7 speed with an old Deore installed, wants to know what she/he can replace it with. Straightforward  with an objective answer.

Comment: I'm probably using this site wrong but I hope you dont mind me asking Argenti but seem pretty knowledgeable with bikes. Also I found a derailleur that will work, you helped a lot. I'm also looking to get a new gear cable and housing. Just to make sure I'm correct as long as the cable is long enough, the right width (mine is 1.2mm) and comes with the other pieces I should be fine correct? This one just gets stuck from time to time. I have the tools needed and looks pretty easy to do. Just dont want to buy the wrong item. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Bentleylou 1.2mm is for gears, 1.6mm for brakes. You need corresponding cable housing, housing caps and that little metal cap on end of cable to prevent splitting. So pretty much everything you can find in shifting/brake cable set. Sharp and strong cutting tool is a must. If you have one of those cheap trash-class rotating shifters you might as well replace them as well. Check out colorful housings, its cheap and simple way to customize your bike (I always had a problem to find my generic bike in crowded bike stand)

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus: One reason might be that the title is very unhelpful; I edited to hopefully improve that. Also, the question shows little research effort, and has little detail: Wha does "messed up" mean? What exactly does not work. OP is apparently new here, and will hopefully learn. In the meantime, there is already a good answer, so everything is fine :-).

Comment: Remember, comments are ephemeral and exist to request clarification or similar.  Try and avoid back-and-forth discussions, instead work the statements into the question or answers with edit.

Answer (score 3):

The derailleur in the picture has been scratched and the cable is connected wrong, but it should work if you install the cable correctly.

Searching for "RD-M53P SGS" does not find anything except this question. However, all Shimano rear derailleurs specified for 9 speeds and below have the same actuation ratio, so any of these should work. The derailleur in the photo looks like 9-speed model and it is installed in 7-speed bike.

Comment: Thanks. And you are correct...it does work. But I like things to be as they should, lol, its also bent in a little. So you say its hooked up wrong...what's wrong with it? I'm sorry to sound like an idiot but I'm a pretty handy person but dont have a clue about working on bikes. I just got into riding in the last few months, something fun to do with my daughter. I appreciate the answer and the help.

Comment: Sorry for the miss wording in my post. I just looked back and realized I said it should work...it does. I just like fixing things on my down time and figured this would be fun and something new to learn.

Comment: The cable should go straight behind bolt. Most derailleurs have a groove for the cable there. A handy person would have looked up a manual, lol.

Comment: I believe the cable needs to be clamped behind the clamping bolt, it should run straight out of the housing boss on the derailleur body.

Comment: "A handy person would of looked up a manual". ojs....sorry but when I search this was one the first things that came up so I thought why not ask (I work on on pavers, milling machines, bobcats, rollers, etc...but I'm not handy at all, just have never messed with all these new things on bikes). Sry but my time is limited, if rather use a place like this to just get a answer. My bad that i work, 50+ hrs a week and I'm a single father to almost 3yo daughter. The 3/4 hours I get alone a day I dont have time to spend like you. Buy thanks for the smartass comment...wasn't needed.

Comment: @Bentleylou: Is it only the derailleur itself which is bent in? Usually the derailleur hanger bends first. You can probably carefully bend it back. Unfortunately a replacement can be hard to find, since it’s specific to the frame.

Comment: @Bentleylou: We understand your time may be limited - but please bear in mind that that applies to many people, also to those helping you here. There are [advice and rules here for how to ask a good question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) - not to annoy you, but to make the site work well for _everyone_. It's fine to ask here if you are stuck and need help, but some effort is required on your part. Anyway, you received a good answer, I hope it helps.